# How to include Glyphicons fonts into Orchard theme?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, orchardcms-1.6, glyphicons

I'm working on a Orchard theme using Twitter Bootstrap 3.0.x

I added all scripts and styles into MyTheme/Scripts & MyTheme/Styles.
It works find except Glyphicons images.

In CSS files, it references icons by using a relative path (../fonts/glyphicon.....).
So I created a MyTheme/fonts containing all glyphicons files.
However, when I browse these files are not found (404).

For example, when I browse the source code :

```
http://localhost:9100/Themes/MyTheme/Scripts/bootstrap.js -> OK
http://localhost:9100/Themes/MyTheme/Styles/bootstrap.css -> OK
http://localhost:9100/Themes/MyTheme/fonts/glyphicons.. -> KO
```

Any idea to do that ?

Comment: I think this question needs general clarification.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late, but maybe it will help other people. You should put your fonts folder in the Content folder looking like this:

```
http://localhost:9100/Themes/MyTheme/Content/fonts/
```

After this you should overwrite in a external css file your bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css the @font-face of your Glyphicons.
Looking like this:

```
    @font-face{
    font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings' !important;
    src:url(../Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot) !important;
    src:url(../Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
        url(../Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff) format('woff'),
        url(../Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf) format('truetype'),
        url(../Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular) format('svg') !important
}
```

Orchard doesn't seem to get content like your fonts outside the Content folder.